# Windows Richedit shows spelling correction suggestions on wrong monitor

Tags: delphi, richedit, spelling, trichedit

I'm using a TRichEdit subclass in a Windows application built with Delphi 10.3. The RichEdit uses class name 'RICHEDIT50W'. In this richedit control I have enabled spelling and auto correction like so:

```
var
  Value: LRESULT;
const
  IMF_TKBAUTOCORRECTION = $2000;
begin
  Value := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETLANGOPTIONS, 0, 0);
  if (FAutoCorrection) then
    Value := Value or IMF_TKBAUTOCORRECTION
  else
    Value := Value and not IMF_TKBAUTOCORRECTION;
  SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, 0, Value);
end;

var
  Value: LRESULT;
const
  IMF_SPELLCHECKING = $0800;
begin
  Value := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETLANGOPTIONS, 0, 0);
  if (FSpellChecking) then
    Value := Value or IMF_SPELLCHECKING
  else
    Value := Value and not IMF_SPELLCHECKING;
  SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, 0, Value);
end;
```

This works fine except when using a second monitor, in that case the spelling correction suggestions popup on the wrong second monitor.

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you mean _popup on the second monitor_? What is the arrangement of your monitors?

Comment: Using two monitors, when the app is running on the secondary monitor, the spelling correction popup appears on first, main monitor.

Comment: Since spellchecks are shown by Windows itself it would seem that for some reason windows is not getting the correct position of the RichEdit control in multi-monitor area. How is this information passed back to windows I don't know

Comment: Just took a look at Delphi 12 source code of `TRichEdit` and it seems that it is encapsulating RichEdit 8. Based on in code comment enabling of spelling and auto-correction seems to be done based on [RichEdit Spell Checking, Autocorrection and Prediction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/richedit-spell-checking-autocorrection-and-prediction) article. I would post the actual code but I'm guessing it is probably copyright protected by Embarcadero.

Comment: Thanks, Simply loading RICHEDIT60W does not work (in fact spellcheck then completely fails). Seems I'll need to upgrade Delphi.